# Is there a setting for black and white printing from iOS?

Tags: ios, printing, airprint

I have a color printer that supports airprint but I don't want to waste the color toner on random docs.  Is there a setting in iOS (iPhone, iPod, iPad) that would allow me to override and print black and white?

Comment: What are you printing from? If it's from the computer you can click print-preview on most any program that supports printing and select black and white.

Comment: The OP indicates *iOS*. Which means, iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iOS 9 AirPrint now has the option to print Black & White.

Screenshot:

[image: Black & White AirPrint]

Answer (score 6):

There [doesn't](http://www.ipadforums.net/airprint/44811-disable-color-airprint-hp-approved-printer-office-pro-8500a.html) [seem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3667091?start=0&tstart=0) [to](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3544200?start=0&tstart=0) be a way to do this natively.

Your options seem to be:

- Get a [black-and-white airprint printer](http://mobileprinting.us/post/14772677854/airprint-black-and-white-laser-printers).
- Use a black-and-white, non-airprint printer with [AirPrint Activator](http://netputing.com/airprintactivator/).
- Use [Epson's app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/epson-iprint/id326876192?mt=8) which [seems](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3544200?start=0&tstart=0) to let you print black-and-white photos.
- Use HP's app which [seems](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3544200?start=0&tstart=0) to let you choose these kind of settings.
- [Tell Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) you want this feature.

Comment: Nice suggestions! +1

Comment: Yeah, unfortunate, but good summary.

Comment: Another option is to put the printer into monochrome mode, if this option exists. This would be done either directly on the printer via buttons on the front, or by accessing the printer's internal "website". Clearly this isn't something you would want to mess with often, but if you rarely print color this is a viable option.